# Resto da divisao em ruby

Tags: ruby

Tenho um *array* de valores:

```
values = [2, 7, 15, 11, 5]
```

Gostaria de pegar somente os valores que a diviso entre eles dão resto *'0'* (retornar *15* e *5*).

Estou conseguindo assim, porém o código vai ler outros *arrays* de números que não são divisíveis por *5*, então teria que cada divisão ser feita dentro do *array*, um pelo outro.

```
values.select{|num| num % 5 == 0}
```

Gostaria de receber o mesmo resultado porém não utilizando o número divisor (5) no caso.

```
[15, 5]
```

Comment: o que você já tem de código?

Comment: Resolvi da forma abaixo, depois de dar uma olhada na documentação, fiz um laço aninhado a outro.

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui resolvendo assim

```
resultado =[]
values.map do |num1|
   divisor = values.select{|num2| num1 % num2 == 0}
resultado << divisor
end
resultado.inject(:+)
```

Fiz um laço dentro de outro para conseguir pegar os valores.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, eu aproveitei para fazer a minha implementação para praticar.

```
values = [2, 7, 15, 11, 5, 30]

new_values = []

values.each {|x| values.each {
 |y| (x % y == 0) and (x != y) ? new_values << x << y : nil }
}


p new_values.uniq

values.each {|x| values.each { |y| (x % y == 0) and (x != y) ? (puts "O resto de #{x} e #{y} = #{x % y}") : nil }}
```

Sua dúvida me ajudou a aprender conceitos novos. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar fazer em bloco também, fica bastante organizado =D

```
resultado = []
values = [2, 7, 15, 11, 5]

values.each { |num| resultado << num if n % 5 == 0 }

puts resultado
```

onde o **each** irá percorrer cada valor da lista **values**, a variável **num** receberá cada **número/valor** e será adicionado ao Array **resultado** se atender a condição.